# Globally toggle css classes?

Tags: css, angular, sass, bootstrap-4

I have some CSS that outlines every div in red.  I use it for debugging to see how elements are aligning.

I have a button that currently toggles a bunch of debugging features on my app.  I'd like to incorporate the toggling of my red outlines as well.

How would I go about toggling these classes considering I'm using angular and the angular cli?  I'd like to avoid dynamically loading and unload the style sheet if at all possible.

Comment: Can you please confirm whether my answer helped you to solve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can take an inspiration from [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) site itself. If you visit the URL, the top bar in the site gives you an option to change the theme. On the similar lines, you can have a CSS dedicated for debug and normal mode each. The debug mode will enable the effect you desire. Under the hood, the Material code does following things.

1. Maintains a list of CSS style list. Search for `themes` variable in
   src\app\shared\theme-picker\theme-picker.ts file.
2. Depending on the option selected by a user, it invokes `setStyle` method
   of `StyleManager` (available in
   src\app\shared\style-manager\style-manager.ts).
3. A `link href` tag in HTML `head` section is manipulated by
   style-manager.

This definitely seems to be a much cleaner approach. The source code of the site can be accessed [here](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io).

Comment: not able to see 'style-manager.ts' in the angular-material github repository. is path is correct?

Comment: My mistake, I copied wrong URL. Updated my answer with correct URL.